# Why is my onContextMenu working but my right onClick doesn't with React Router Dom and Styled Components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components, right-click

Trying to fire an onClick with `onContextMenu` I can detect right click in my child component and a left click works but for some reason the onClick doesn't work when a right click is done.

Styled Component:

```js
export const NavLogo = styled(Link)`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  justify-self: flex-start;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`
```

Child Component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

// Styled Components
import { NavLogo, NavIcon } from './NavbarElements'

const Logo = ({ click }) => {
  const history = useHistory()

  const rightClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    return history.push('/foo')
  }

  return (
    <NavLogo to="/" onClick={click} onContextMenu={rightClick}>
      <NavIcon />
      Foobar
    </NavLogo>
  )
}

export default Logo
```

parent component (stripped down):

```js
const Navbar = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
  const [button, setButton] = useState(true)

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)
  const mobile = () => setClick(false)

  const showButton = () => {
    window.innerWidth <= 960 ? setButton(false) : setButton(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    showButton()
  }, [])

  window.addEventListener('resize', showButton)

  return (
    <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
      <Nav>
        <NavbarContainer>
          <Logo click={mobile} />
        </NavbarContainer>
      </Nav>
    </IconContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

when a regular click is done the onClick works. In my research I didn't find a solution:

- [React Synthetic Event distinguish Left and Right click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110184/react-synthetic-event-distinguish-left-and-right-click-events)
- [react-router-dom Link onclick get the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382650/react-router-dom-link-onclick-get-the-path)
- [Right Click Menu using React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648292/right-click-menu-using-react-js)
- [How to implement mouse on-RightClick into list item of Material UI with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465604/how-to-implement-mouse-on-rightclick-into-list-item-of-material-ui-with-reactjs)

In my child component how should the onClick be used to work with a `onContextMenu` right click?